# Print column 1 and 4 that have the less price using awk

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have this file that contains the car name, colour and price:

```
   Toyota#Red#4500
   Sedan#Blue#2600
   Hyunda#Black#5000
   Dudge#White#3900
   Lymozeen#Black#2400
```

The output should display the car name and the price that is less than 5000:

```
   Lymozeen#2400
   Sedan#2600
   Dudge#3900
   Toyota#4500
```

I have tried this following code:

```
awk '{if($3 <= 5000)print $1,$3}' myfile
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"} $3 < 5000 {print $1,$3}' myfile`

Comment: Where is the question/issue ? What is not working with your code ? Missing informations

Comment: So you also would like to sort your output according to the third column?

Comment: Yes that will help@Paolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest breaking this up. First, sort the content of the file based on the value of the third column, then select the lines of interest with your condition. Here's how:

```
awk -F'#' '{ print $NF, $0}' myfile | sort -n | awk -F'[# ]' '{if($1<5000)print $5"#"$7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

One in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="#"                            # set field separators
}
$3<5000 {                                 # if less than 5k
    a[NR]=$3                              # on NR hash price
    b[NR]=$1                              # on NR hash brand
}
END {                                     # in the end
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"  # set for traverse order
    for(i in a)                           # loop in ascendeing price order
        print b[i],a[i]                   # output
}' file
```

Output:

```
Lymozeen#2400
Sedan#2600
Dudge#3900
Toyota#4500
```